# How do I make a link for jumping to another section of the page?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm making an apps script on a Google site, and I'm embedding it with a gadget. I would like to make a link within the gadget that can jump down to another section of the page, but I have not found a way to do this. I found the anchor command, but it opens the link in a new page by default.

Is there any way to jump to a specific section of a page using apps script without re-loading the page in a new window?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is an anchor tag.  Check this reference:  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_anchor

Comment: could you elaborate please ?